# SharePoint - Create email alert when user comments on a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-email, sharepoint-alerts

Is it possible to create an alert and send it to multiple email ids? That is

When someone writes a comment here 
[image]

An email alert goes out to a few email ids that 'someone has commented'. I tried looking at Microsoft Flow to cater to this need but unfortunately it does not have it.

Comment: You can get the comments using REST APIs as given [here](https://www.vrdmn.com/2017/07/working-with-page-comments-rest-api-in.html). Check this if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to send email to multiple person when comments are added to the page - it is something like workflow or Flow triggers on the SharePoint list - when someone writes a comment on the page it goes and sits in the comment list, so you need to write a flow on the comment hidden list and you can send email to multiple recipients.

Now, the question is how and where can we find this comment hidden list?

Please read the below details thread from Microsoft for that where it has been discussed wisely.

[Alerts on Comments in Modern Pages?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/alerts-on-comments-in-modern-pages/m-p/227572)

**Another approach**

Using the Microsoft Flow and graph API we can send emails to multiple recipients when comments are added by following the below steps :

1. Creating and registering an Office 365 app with access permissions to MS Graph API.
2. Authentication/Authorization call from MS Flow using custom app credentials from p.1.
3. Calling MS Graph API from MS Flow using token from p.2.

Details implementation is here :

[USING MICROSOFT GRAPH API INSIDE MICROSOFT FLOW IN OFFICE](https://www.infopulse.com/blog/using-microsoft-graph-api-inside-microsoft-flow-office-365/)

Answer (score 0):

using the below powerAutomate from the App Source
https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dynamics-365/hansaplusgmbh1647344474007.hp_05809820228?tab=Overview
you can get notified with the latest comments and replies on your Site page and News Post